# Response rate when denominator is unknown

Tags: survey

I have conducted a survey. I advertised the survey (with survey link) on social media, I used listservs to send out the survey link, I displayed the survey notification (with survey link) on notice boards, and I also used snow ball method to recruit survey participants. In other words, I do not know how many people came across the survey information and decided to not respond to it. Is it possible to calculate a response rate in this case? If yes, what would be the denominator to calculate the response rate for my survey? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In short, not really.  You could estimate how many people would have seen your survey, but with a huge margin of error.

Think of how many people see a Listserv notification and think *"Not another self-serving promotional stunt..."*.  Consider the number of people who saw this ad on notice boards and didn't even give it a second thought.  Trying to calculate the number of people on your social media accounts who *may* have seen the link in passing is near-impossible.

You would have been able to do this if you had *only* sent out emails or person-to-person messages with "read receipts" attached to them.  However, since you included Listervs (which mess with "read receipt"-like programs) and bulletin boards, calculating the ballpark number of people who came across the ad would have massive error, and is not useful in any sort of statistical analysis.